# :focus-within styles flash when clicking an input label

Tags: css

### Problem:

Clicking on an input label within a parent element with `:focus-within` styles causes an undesirable flash of the `:focus-within` styles.

---

### Background:

I wanted to use `:focus-within` to improve accessibility by providing the user with some visual feedback when a group of related radio-buttons is in focus.

Attaching labels to the radio buttons allows the user to click a label to select the corresponding radio button. However, clicking the label causes the `:focus-within` styles to flash off while the mouse is down.

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <label><input type="radio" name="x"/>First</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="x"/>Second</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="x"/>Third</label>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.parent {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;

    &:focus-within {
        background: skyblue;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggamir/nb3sy26k/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Add `tabindex="-1"` to the labels. This allows them to become "focusable" elements without being part of the tabindex order.

https://jsfiddle.net/ggamir/krnavadz/

---

#### Explanation

When a user begins clicking on a label (`mousedown`), the previously focused radio button loses its `:focus` state.

When the user completes the click (`mouseup`) on a label, the browser selects the corresponding radio button and gives it a`:focus` state.

By default, the `label` element is "unfocusable", so while the mouse is down on the label, nothing in the parent has focus, which is why the `:focus-within` styles are removed for that moment.

Adding `tabindex` to the label makes it a "focusable" element, so while the mouse clicks down on it, the parent still has `:focus-within`, so the styles will remain applied throughout the whole duration of the click.

Using `-1` in `tabindex="-1"` is important so that the label doesn't unnecessarily get added into the tabindex order.

#### Note

There are some default `:focus` and `:active` styles for elements which will be applied to the label once it is made "focusable" through `tabindex`, so clearing those may be desired so as to not confuse the user:

```
.my-label:focus, .my-label:active {
    outline: none;
}
```